# red.shared instruction

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I am learning CUDA and after looking through the PTX manual, 
I found that there is an instruction called red.shared which performs
reduction across a warp.

I am curious whether or not the hardware has native support for reductions.
And if it does, how can one use it in CUDA code? Perhaps someone has experimented with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually it happens to be so that I also experimented with 'red' instruction out of curiosity. I don't know how this is on Kepler but on Fermi architecture 'red' instruction just maps to a sequence of another instructions. Maybe they left it for future GPUs. Here is the code I played with:

```
#define WS 32
#define HF 16

__global__ void test_red_kernel(unsigned *g_R, const unsigned *g_U) {

  extern __shared__ unsigned shared[];

  unsigned thid = threadIdx.x, bidx_x = blockIdx.x;
  unsigned *r = shared;
  unsigned ofs = bidx_x << 7, thid_in_warp = thid & WS-1;

  unsigned a = (g_U + ofs)[thid];

  volatile unsigned *t = (volatile unsigned *)r + HF + UMUL(thid >> 5,
        WS + HF + 1) + thid_in_warp;

  t[-HF] = 0;
t[0] = a;
// warp reduction
a = a + t[-HF], t[0] = a;
a = a + t[-8], t[0] = a;
a = a + t[-4], t[0] = a;
a = a + t[-2], t[0] = a;
a = a + t[-1], t[0] = a;

CU_SYNC

volatile unsigned *t2 = r + HF + UMUL(WS*4 >> 5, WS + HF + 1);

if(thid < 4) {

    unsigned loc_ofs = HF + WS-1 + UMUL(thid, WS + HF + 1);
    unsigned a2;

    volatile unsigned *ps = t2 + thid;
    ps[-2] = 0;

    a2 = r[loc_ofs]; ps[0] = a2;
    a2 = a2 + ps[-2], ps[0] = a2;
    a2 = a2 + ps[-1], ps[0] = a2;
}

CU_SYNC

a = a + t2[(thid >> 5) - 1];

unsigned b;      
asm volatile("mov.u32 %r11, shared;" : );
asm volatile("red.shared.add.u32 [%r11], %0;" :
            "+r"(b) : );

b = r[0]; // results of 'red.shared', compare it with a

(g_R + ofs)[thid] = a - b; 
}
```

to see how 'red' instruction is implemented in the hardware you can use cuobjdump tool on 
the produced 'cubin' file (use option -keep with nvcc)

Comment: cool, thanks.. I did not know that CUDA supports inline assembler. Is that cuobjdump program you mentioned included in cuda distribution ?

Comment: Kepler chips can perform warp-wide reduction without having to use shared or global memory (lane shuffle). The instruction in its current form might become deprecated.